# How do I add a reference when building a single file in MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio?

Tags: .net, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I am working on a single file (not a project or solution) with Xamarin Studio, but I can't build it because I can't reference some DLLs in the same directory. *Without* making a new project (as this is overkill), how do I tell the IDE to reference those libraries, explicitly or automatically, when compiling this single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how a project is overkill for this - it's a single XML file that would reference the file and assemblies in the directory and provide compiler options. Without a solution or multiple build configurations, you can slim it down to probably 10-20 lines, and would simplify building cross-platform, similar to a Makefile.

However, this is still possible to do. On the command line you can reference assemblies with the `/r` or `/reference` options. For example:

```
mcs /reference:System.Drawing.dll Main.cs
```

would reference `System.Drawing`. You may also need to specify the current directory as one where assemblies exist. This might *just work*, but in case it doesn't, it would be the `/lib` or `-L` options. More details on the [mcs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mcs).

I don't believe MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio has any built-in way to include those compiler options from within the source file, but it does have the ability to invoke Makefiles, so throw your version of the `mcs` command into a `Makefile` in the same directory and you should be able to invoke it from MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I'm just going to set this as an answer because I also ended up compiling via the command line. At first I was attracted to Xamarin Studio because of its nice UI, but now I don't like it because of its instability. Oh well.

Comment: It's a lot better than it used to be a few years ago. It just might not like you not having a project file (Visual Studio doesn't like it either), as it uses the .csproj file to pull in references for autocomplete, etc.